# How can I include php file in my module without using composer?

Tags: 8

I want include PHP file in drupal 8 module.
What is the best way for it ?

Answer (score 2):

Outside of autoloading, the only option Drupal provides itself is [`module_load_include()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21module.inc/function/module_load_include/8.2.x), which literally

> Loads a module include file.
>
> Examples:

```
// Load node.admin.inc from the node module.
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.admin');
// Load content_types.inc from the node module.
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'content_types');
```

The final part of the description is worth taking in separately as it's important:

> Do not use this function to load an install file, use module_load_install() instead. Do not use this function in a global context since it requires Drupal to be fully bootstrapped, use require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/path/file' instead.

It's also worth noting this function won't be around forever, the plan is to move it completely into the module handler service.

Comment: Could be that the file doesn't exist. Check the return value, the code of `module_load_include` is very small so you'll easily be able to work out which part is going wrong. I can't do that from here